# Multiple related schemas using jaxb2

Tags: java, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using jaxb2 for a rest webservice.

I need to use two schemas. One is my own schema, stored in the src/main/resources/schema folder, and another schema, which is an online schema http://mypage.com/1/meta/schema.xsd. The problem is that both schemas have duplicated imports, so when I try to build the package, it gives me an issue with both executions saying that certain classes were already defined before.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use separate schema compilation for that, i.e. out of each schema file a JAR is created.